# tecplot 360: convert face-centered data to node data

Tags: software, plotting

Is there a way **in** Tecplot to change data from face-centred to node-based?
If I look at the plot, it seems to me that internally Tecplot is changing the data from being at the centre of the face to being at the corner nodes - is this a correct observation and can this data be written to a file?

Comment: That's true, tecplot interpolates somehow to the nodes. But if you select "primary value" you will get the cell-centered data. I think you can export the interpolated data to file in tecplot format (.dat or .plt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data can be interpolated when importing it into Tecplot.
If the cell-centred data is imported from a CGNS-file, the [Tecplot manual](http://download.tecplot.com/360/current/tpum.pdf) has this to offer:

- Load Cell-centered Data Directly: Toggle-on to load cell-centered data directly [default]. When the option is toggled-off, cell-centered data will be averaged to the nodes (using the averaging method specified below).
- Averaging: This option is available only if “Load Cell-centered Directly” is not selected. When the field variables are stored at cell centers, either Laplacian averaging or arithmetic averaging may be used to average the cell data to the nodes they surround. This can result in a bias at the boundary nodes. Arithmetic averaging is automatically used for ordered/structured zones. When available, Rind data is used in the averaging.